# How to use Subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to execute following shell command in python: `grep 'string' file | tail -1 | cut -c 1-3`

I tried:

```
import subprocess

i = 1
while i < 1070:
    file = "sorted." + str(i) + ".txt"
    string = "2x"
    subprocess.call(grep 'string' file | tail -1 | cut -c 1-3)
    i = i + 1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look anywhere how to pass the commands ?

Comment: Like for example here; https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, whatever you pass into the `subprocess.call` should be a string. Names `grep`, `file`, `tail` and `cut` are not defined in your code and you need to turn the whole expression into a string. Since the search string for the grep command should be dynamic, you need to construct the final string before passing it as argument into the function.

```
import subprocess

i = 1
while i < 1070:
    file = "sorted." + str(i) + ".txt"
    string = "2x"
    command_string = 'grep {0} {1} | tail -1 | cut -c 1-3'.format(string, file)
    subprocess.call(command_string)
    i = i + 1
```

You probably want to pass in an additional argument to `subprocess.call`: `shell=True`. The argument will make sure the command is executed through the shell.

Your command is using `cut`. You might want to retrieve the output of the subprocess, so a better option would be to create a new process object and use `subprocess.communicate` with turned out output capturing:

```
import subprocess

i = 1
while i < 1070:
    file = "sorted." + str(i) + ".txt"
    string = "2x"
    command_string = 'grep {0} {1} | tail -1 | cut -c 1-3'.format(string, file)

    p = subprocess.Popen(command_string, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()

    # stdoutdata now contains the output of the shell commands and you can use it
    # in your program

    i = i + 1
```

EDIT: Here is the information on how to store the data into a text file, as requested in the comment.

```
import subprocess

outputs = []

i = 1
while i < 1070:
    file = "sorted." + str(i) + ".txt"
    string = "2x"
    command_string = 'grep {0} {1} | tail -1 | cut -c 1-3'.format(string, file)

    p = subprocess.Popen(command_string, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()

    # stdoutdata now contains the output of the shell commands and you can use it
    # in your program, like writing the output to a file.

    outputs.append(stdoutdata)

    i = i + 1


with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(outputs))
```

Comment: Note that this this command would be vulnerable to shell injection for a untrusted `string` or `file`

Comment: @mousetail Of course, in a real application with some user inputs, the data would need to be validated and sanitized before passing it in.

Comment: This returns `AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'communicate'`

Comment: @yellowcab True, the method comes from the Popen object. Fixed that now.

Comment: I would like to print the results to a text file. How could I do that?

Comment: This returns `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`. How could I print the results to one text file?

Comment: @yellowcab You didn't specify which Python you were using. It's now updated for Python 3 and the results are stored into a single file at the end of the script.

Comment: I can't see anything in output.txt.

Comment: @yellowcab You need to check the outputs of each iteration of the `for` loop. If there is nothing in the final file, it probably means that your command didn't produce anything. You have the data and you're the only one who can debug it.

Comment: I checked the outputs of each iteration of the `while` loop. At `i = 219` the output is `1`. At `i = 1069` the output is `112`. The program runs into an error if I have `i < 219`. Also how could I print the results so that there is no blank line between the numbers?

Comment: @yellowcab Please create a new question focusing on formatting the values since the original question seems to be solved now. It will be more efficient to move the discussion to a new question instead of putting everything into comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Subprocess expects the arguments as a string or array:

```
subprocess.call("grep '{}' {} | tail -1 | cut -c 1-3".format(string, file), shell=True)
```

`shell=True` is nececairy because you are using shell-specific commands like the pipe.

However, in this case it might be a lot easier to implement the entire program in pure python.

Note that if either string or file contain any special characters including spaces or quotation marks, the command will not work, and could in fact do a variety of unwanted things to your system. If you need it to work on more than these simple values, consider either a pure-python solution, setting `shell=False` and using the array syntax with manual piping, or some form of escaping.

Comment: This command will search for file named `file`. To adjust it according to the given code, use this instead `subprocess.call("grep 'string' {} | tail -1 | cut -c 1-3".format(file), shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Your command should be provided as a string. 
In addition, if you want to get the output of your command, you can use the following:

```
subprocess.run("grep 'string' file | tail -1 | cut -c 1-3", shell=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
```

where `capture_output` (works in Python3.7+) returns object with `returncode`, `stdout` and `stderr` and the `check` flag will raise exception if your command fails.